# Extrema of functions of two variables: necessary and sufficient conditions

Tags: functions

I seem to recall my teacher telling us about the necessary and sufficient conditions while finding the maxima/minima of functions. However, I can no longer find those conditions in my booklet and even on the internet. Can someone please tell me about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applies to local extrema only.

Given differentiable $F(x,y),$  a necessary condition for a local extreme to occur at a point $(x_0,y_0)$  is that the gradient satisfies $\nabla F(x_0,y_0)=0.$  (that is, both partial derivatives must vanish at $(x_0,y_0).$

A sufficient condition for a local extreme is that $\nabla F(x_0,y_0)=0$ and the Hessian $$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} f_{xx}(x_0,y_0) & f_{xy}(x_0,y_0)  \\ f_{xy}(x_0,y_0) & f_{yy}(x_0,y_0) \end{array}\right]$$ satisfies one one of:

1) $f_{xx}(x_0,y_0) f_{yy}(x_0,y_0) - [f_{xy}(x_0,y_0)]^2 \neq 0$ and $f_{xx}(x_0,y_0) + f_{yy}(x_0,y_0)>0$  (Local Min)

2)  $f_{xx}(x_0,y_0) f_{yy}(x_0,y_0) - [f_{xy}(x_0,y_0)]^2$ and $f_{xx}(x_0,y_0) + f_{yy}(x_0,y_0)<0$  (Local Max)

Comment: I think it should be emphasized that, as you wrote, these are **local** extrema. I'm not aware of any general methods of finding the global ones.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä. Thanks.   For constrained problems with reasonably strict assumptions on the constraints, there are the KKT conditions.

Comment: That sufficient condition, is also a necessary condition?

Answer (score 0):

see also here, you will find the second derivative test

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html